# Motorola handheld terminal barcode scanning in background

Tags: c#, windows-ce, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk, datawedge

There are a lot of applications (like DataWedge, Terminal Emulator, etc..) that may use barcode scanner on handheld terminal like MC9090 with Windows CE. All this application connects to barcode scanner resources and gets data from it.

Is it possible to connect to barcode scanner while different application is using this scanner? Is it possible with Motorola .net C# EMDK or some different way? From my experience ehen some application is using barcode scanner and my application try to use this barcode scanner the exception is fired.

My goal is to write Windows CE application that will work in background and collect all data scanned by any different application.

Comment: See: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: It depends on the model of your scanner and how you are connecting to it. If your scanner is connected to a network via Ethernet then you could even have multiple computers attach to it by opening the same TCP port on each.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. Maybe I did not explained correctly. I will add some edit.

Comment: we use MC9090 quite a lot and while I have never tried this I can tell you that once you have the device activated and waiting for scanning (using the .net C# EMDK) other applications will not be able to do so too (or vice versa) - but to be honest I never needed this as we have our own app always topmost and basically as the only running app

Comment: still there might be some way to do this but I would suggest you ask Motorola (or is it Zebra now? .. I can never tell the little tags on the scanners change all the time ;)) directly - maybe there is a low-level API you can insert a hook into

Comment: Yes, its Zebra now. I have asked them, but still no answer...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer: it is possible using Motorola EMDK. The scanner must be opened in Monitor mode. And then use scanner API as normal.